# trying to login from facebook sdk earlier it was working fine but now giving error?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

1.trying to login from facebook sdk earlier it was working fine but now giving after login from different account its giving "domain=com.facebook.sdk.login code=304 "  error.
below is my code

```
- (IBAction)fbLoginClick:(id)sender
{

    if ([AppDelegate getAppDelegate].internetActive) {  

        FBSDKLoginManager * login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

        [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email",@"user_birthday",@"user_friends",@"user_posts"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

            if (!error)
            {
                NSMutableArray *grantedPermission = (NSMutableArray *)result.grantedPermissions;
                if(![grantedPermission containsObject:@"public_profile"] || ![grantedPermission containsObject:@"email"] || ![grantedPermission containsObject:@"user_birthday"] || ![grantedPermission containsObject:@"user_friends"] || ![grantedPermission containsObject:@"user_posts"])
                {

                    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email",@"user_birthday",@"user_friends",@"user_posts"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
                     {
                         if(result.token)
                         {
                             [self getFacebookProfileInfos];
                         }

                     }];

                }
                else
                {
                    [self getFacebookProfileInfos];
                }
                // There is an error here.

            }


        }];      
}
else
{

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet Connection" message:@"Please check Internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
</i>
```

Answer (score 3):

you try this code to solve your problem

you get access token then logout your session.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *logMeOut = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[logMeOut logOut];
```

In your case you get accessTokens then logout fb session.